# Java - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to run my code and it says something about the exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

I googled it, from what I understand it happens when I try to access an index that's negative or greater than my array length.
But I can't seem to find the problem, here's my code: http://pastebin.com/sXsBbYfh

Thanks for any helpers.

EDIT: the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at Calculator.addOne(Calculator.java:127)
at Calculator.add(Calculator.java:88)
at Program.main(Program.java:8)
```

About the relevant part of the code, I have no idea, that's why i'm coming to you.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the code here along with the stack trace?

Comment: Please. Can you post the stackTrace about this exception?:

Comment: which code line does the exception gets thrown at?

Comment: can you please post the line which give the exception. Plus for future reference when you post questions please post the necessary code snippet in the question body. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you use an ide debugger. Put a stop point where it is throwing the exception and work backwards.

Comment: Well, there are hell lot of logical errors in that code. But the one which throws the exception is - `this.addOne(arrResult.length);`, here you are passing the length of array, and using it as `index` in the `addOne` method. Change this invocation to - `this.addOne(arrResult.length - `);`. Note that, this will not solve all the issue. And I have no courage to pin down every problem here.

Comment: One line also worries me: `String[] arrNum1 = stringNum1.split("");` not related to the error, but are you sure you want to split after every character?

Comment: Seems the code full of errors.

Comment: @jlordo.. Common, there are many lines that worries me. You are far behind. lol.. Move ahead the code and you will find them.. ;)

Comment: Note that the error message was telling you the "relevant" part of your code.

at Calculator.addOne(Calculator.java:127)  tells you its happening on line 127.  From there you can track back to where the problem really is.

Comment: @jlordo yes I do. And thanks everyone, you solved it.

Comment: @shohamh.. No, it isn't solved. First remove all the logical errors, then only your code would work as expected.

Comment: @RohitJain I'm working on it. I was just trying to make sure I can print the result of the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue would appear to be with line 86

```
  arrResult = this.addOne(arrResult.length);
```

Array indexes are 0 based, so 0 - length-1  and you are passing length in and then using that to access your array on line 127

```
  switch(arrResult[arrayIndex])
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of code :

```
public int[] addOne(int arrayIndex)

 124.
        {

 125.
                switch(arrResult[arrayIndex])

 126.
                {

 127.
                        case 0:

 128.
                                arrResult[arrayIndex] = 1;
```

Is source of error.

Note that.

In java, arrays index range from 0 to length-1

In your code above, when method `addon()` is called , you are passing array length as parameter, and in code above you are trying to access `array[length]` which does not exist and hence the exception. Thus you may want to keep that `length-1`

In the following code line #86

```
    arrResult = this.addOne(arrResult.length);
```

There are lot of logical errors in your code. This is just the one that throws the exception you mentioned